# JavaScript regex freezing browser

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am using the following regex in JavaScript to validate an input field:

```
    <textarea
           id="kpf-message-textarea"
           class="message-area"
           name="message"
           maxlength="1000"
           aria-describedby="kpf-message-extra-text"
           aria-invalid="true"
           tabindex={this.kpfTabindex}
           value={this.message}
            onInput={(event) => this._handleChange(event)}>
           </textarea>


this.message.match(/^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]| 
[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]|[ \\.^°!"²§³$%&\/\\{\\}\\ 
(\\)=?´`@€+-\\*~'#<>|µ,;:_<CR><LF>]|[\n])+$/)
```

For the follwing pattern with 30 capital alphabets and one invalid character, it causes the browser to hang and only closing and opening the brower again helps:

```
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPAAAAAAAAAAAAAA¼
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: It is due to catastrophic backtracking. If the pattern can not match, it will backtrack and try all options. Why not without all the separate character classes? ``^[A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ \\.^°!"²§³$%&\/{} ()=?´`@€+*~'#<>|µ,;:_<CR><LF>\n-]+$`` https://regex101.com/r/S7ZWvH/1

Comment: You might also post the actual JavaScript where you try this so we might help you best (what is "message"?, can we assume that string example?

Comment: I have added more info

Comment: @Thefourthbird I dont get your point? How can I improve/correct this regex to work?

Comment: @user1107888 Did you try the pattern in the comment above?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have tried your suggestion and its working, thank you:) Now, if you will be kind enough to either shortly explain why it was not working with character groups or point me to a relevant source? I  found some answers related to catastrophic backtracking but didnt understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern times out due to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

It can not match the character `¼` at the end, and it will still try to explore (backtrack) all paths. With the outer repeating group, and the alternations inside that group, there are a lot of options.

Using `[<CR><LF>]` in the character class is the same as `[><CFLR]` If you want to match a carriage return or a linefeed you can use `\r\n`

As you use the alternation `|` for all single character matches (character classes without a quantifier), you can merge all character classes to a single character class and repeat the character class 1 or more times.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ \\.^°!"²§³$%&/{} ()=?´`@€+*~'#<>|µ,;:_\r\n-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpf31T/1)

A simplified example:

```js
function handleChange() {
  let elm = document.getElementById("kpf-message-textarea");
  if (/^[A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ \\.^°!"²§³$%&/{} ()=?´`@€+*~'#<>|µ,;:_\r\n-]+$/.test(elm.value)) {
    console.log("Match: " + elm.value);
  } else {
    console.log("No match: " + elm.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="kpf-message-textarea" class="message-area" name="message" maxlength="1000" aria-invalid="true" onInput=handleChange()>
</textarea>
```